# Insert from SAS into Amazon RDS (mysql) not working even though log shows inserted rows

Tags: mysql, sas, amazon-rds

I am trying to insert records from SAS table into Amazon RDS using ODBC libname statement. 
My log shows that records have been inserted , however the select query returns null. I tried commit after insert, but it is still not working.

When i try inserting from sql prompt it works.

I am trying a normal proc sql statement .

Code :-

```
libname test1 odbc user=XX password="XX" datasrc="Amazon RDS ODBC DSN"    autocommit=yes dbcommit =1000;
proc sql;
insert into test1.tmp_list (cust_iden, process_id) values (1,10);
select * from test1.tmp_list;
quit;
```

Log output :-

```
*NOTE: Libref TEST1 was successfully assigned as follows:  
      Engine:        ODBC  
      Physical Name: Amazon RDS ODBC DSN  
3          proc sql;  
4          insert into test1.tmp_list (cust_iden, process_id) values (1,10);  
NOTE: 1 row was inserted into TEST1.tmp_list.  
5          select * from test1.tmp_list;  
NOTE: No rows were selected.  
6  
7          quit;  
NOTE: PROCEDURE SQL used (Total process time):  
      real time           0.09 seconds  
      cpu time            0.05 seconds*
```

There is no error displayed in the log which indicates a rollback. Where is my record disappearing? I want to be able load a list of cust_iden's from a sas dataset into this temp tables. 
Any pointers would be helpful.
Thanks.

Comment: You should post your code and log at minimum

Comment: What happens if your select is in a separate query/proc?

Comment: I am getting the same result even when the select query is in a different proc. I also logged into the database server, but none of the records have been added to the table.

Comment: I would raise a ticket with SAS Tech Support if you haven't already. You should only find one record added, not sure why you mention records?

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, I started out with a table of cust_iden that had to be loaded into this table. When it did not work I did this trial of only 1 record. But I still struck to the records terminology. The above code should insert 1 record.

Comment: Is there any change if you execute an ANALYZE TABLE tmp_list  PERSISTENT FOR ALL on the table between insertion and selection?